# Extend Visual Studio Team System 2010 SSC

Tags: tfs

I'm looking to extend the source control of Visual Studio 2010 Team System. I need to halt the check-in process and pop-up a little GUI to do some things. I've found this; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182075(VS.100).aspx, does anybody have any good tutorials or similar lying around i'd appreciate it.

Comment: Not all checkins use the GUI (e.g. "tf checkin" from command line, buddy build will checkin from build server), so seems like a poor time to do something interactive.

Comment: Actually, even command-line check-ins are subjected to check-in policies. You can also install them on your build machines if you want them applied by 2010's gated check-in feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is a check-in policy. If you download and install the latest VS 2008 SDK, you can re-compile the check-in sample in VS 2010 after fixing up the assembly references. We'll be publishing update SDK samples when Beta 2 is released.